# moving files from subfolders to one folder

Tags: batch-file, subdirectory

I have a folder with 5 steps deep folders and every folder has only one file. i want to move all files out to the main folder. ( i mean i want to get rid of subfolders completely, i need only the files in them) . like this:

folder/folder1/folder11/folder111/folder1111/folder11111/file-1.html
folder/folder2/folder22/folder222/folder2222/folder22222/file-2.html
folder/folder3/folder33/folder333/folder3333/folder33333/file-3.html
.
.
.

i want all .html files out in the "folder"

folder/file-1.html,file-2.html,.....

what is the batch file for this issue.

thanks in advance if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this small batch file (create a `foo.bat` file):

```
@echo off
set dest=dest_dir
for /F %%a in ('dir /B /S /A-D folder') do move /-Y %%a %dest%\%%~na%%~xa
```

it scans the files (not directories) contained in the `folder` directory and moves them to `dest_dir`

Note: there's a safety to avoid overwriting files with the same name (`/-Y`) option. You are prompted if it happens.

Comment: strange as I pasted the exact code above in a `foo.bat` file and it worked fine for me. Maybe remove the first echo off and see what is printed... Outside a script, the syntax is different: `%%a` becomes `%a` and so on. So it's important that you copy the code in a batch file.